# How to do checked checkbox from formarray in angular 8 on specific condition

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I am sharing my code as I am trying to show list of items in form of checkboxes and on dropdown selection it check for certain condition if it matched then, checkbox should be checked dynamically. I have tried number of options but unable to succeed.

HTML code : here showing list of items in form of checkboxes. On dropdown selection it should show list of privileges given to all roles in common and show checkboxes checked for privileges given to the selected role

```
<nz-card>                
    <div class="row">
        <div>                       
            <label><h5>Role List</h5></label> 
        </div>
        <div>                              
            <nz-select
            nzPlaceHolder="Select Role"
            [nzShowArrow]="true"
            [(ngModel)]="chosenRole"
            (ngModelChange)="onselectRole($event)" 
            name="selectRole"  style="max-width: 500px;">
                <nz-option *ngFor="let s of roleList" [nzValue]="s.roleid" [nzLabel]="s.name"></nz-option>
            </nz-select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="row" *ngIf="showPrivleges">
        <form  [formGroup]="privilegeform"  (ngSubmit)="updatePrivleges()"> 
        <div class="col-md-2" >   
            <label><h5>Privilege List</h5></label> 
        </div>
             <div  formArrayName="privileges" *ngFor="let privilege of getformArray().controls; let i = index" >
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                        [formControlName]="i" />
                        {{privilegeList[i].name}}
                    </label></div>
                </div>
                <br/> 
            </div>
            <button  nz-button nzType="primary"  nzBlock>Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nz-card>
```

typescript code : here fetching data from api and checking for condition on selected option from dropdown menu , If condition matched it should do checked on particular checkbox with index in formarray

```
 constructor(private fb : FormBuilder,private roleprisrv: AuthenticationRoleService, private modalService: NzModalService, private message: NzMessageService) 
  {
      this.privilegeform = this.fb.group({
        privileges: []
      });
  }
  
  ngOnInit() : void {    
    //Load Role List  
    this.roleprisrv.getRoleList().subscribe(data =>{
      this.roleList = data;
    });
        //Load Privilege List     
        this.roleprisrv.getPrivilegeList().subscribe(data =>{
          this.privilegeList = data;     
            this.privilegeform = this.fb.group({
              privileges: new FormArray([])
            });
              this.addCheckboxes();
          });
    }
    
    private addCheckboxes() {
      this.privilegeList.forEach(() => this.getformArray().push(new FormControl(false)));
    }
    
    getformArray() : FormArray {
       return this.privilegeform.controls.privileges as FormArray;
    }
    
    onselectRole(id:String)
      {
                this.chosenRole=id;                
                this.roleprisrv.getRolePrivlegeList(id).subscribe(rolePrivList =>{
                  var rolePrivListTemp : any= rolePrivList;
                  var privMap = this.privilegeform.value.privileges.map;
                  var privIndex = 0;
                  this.privilegeList.forEach(privelement => { 
                    var status : boolean = false;            
                    var privId = this.privilegeList[privIndex].privilegeid;              
                    var privExist = false;
                    rolePrivListTemp.forEach(function(childObj: any){
                          if(privelement.privilegeid===childObj.privilegeid ){
                            privExist=true;
                          }
                      })
                      if(privExist){
       
                        this.privilegeform.value.privileges[privIndex] = true; 
                   this.privilegeform.controls.privileges.value[privIndex];
                    
            
                       } 
                      
                      privIndex++;
                  });
                  this.showPrivleges=true; //: TODO implement in front end
                  
                });
        
        }
```

My problem is that I am unable to checked checkbox. I am doing but it is right way to do this

```
 if(privExist)
{
       this.privilegeform.value.privileges[privIndex] = true;                      
       this.privilegeform.controls.privileges.value[privIndex];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this issue I added  this.getformArray().controls[privIndex].setValue(privExist); It bind to form array control. I added in this block rolePrivListTemp.forEach(function(childObj: any){ if(privelement.privilegeid===childObj.privilegeid ){ privExist=true; } }) this.getformArray().controls[privIndex].setValue(privExist);